# Rails scss background image not work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I need to create `div` which include background image, and I've tried many ways, but none of these is working.

```
.tiket{
background: url('ticket.png');
background-image: image-url('ticket.png');
background-image: asset-url("ticket.png", image);
background-image: asset-data-url("ticket.png");
}
```

But if I open the chrome develop debugger, it will show picture like this 
[image]

Here is [github](https://github.com/fifiteen82726/agriblack/blob/master/app/views/posts/show.html.erb), if you need more information, please tell me.

### Update

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukjn868r/)

Comment: If div does't have height property or content inside, then the bg image will not show up.

Comment: How about trying `background-image: url(image_path('ticket.png'));`

Comment: In the div, it contain picture and text, I think it's not a problem.

Comment: background-image: url(image_path('ticket.png')); not work, but it still show in chrome develop debugger, it's weird.

Comment: Can you post a snippet, or point to a website, that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Why did you nest a bootstrap column div inside another column div without putting a row inbetween?

Comment: I will post a demo later, actually I don't know exactly what  `row` mean?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I'm too new to do so; sorry. The .ticket div can still have a height of zero if all of its children are floated or otherwise taken out of flow. If you inspect the .ticket div, what width/height are given?